# Two theme options pages for a theme

Tags: theme-development

i am currently using a theme options page for a theme im building buti  am looking to add another for advance settings. is there a way of doing this?

Both would be using the same options would this casue a issue?

Comment: Please explain your question with some code you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way of doing this?

Yes, just go and do it? There is no inherent or implied limit to creating admin pages.

> Both would be using the same options would this casue a issue?

No, unless you code it in a way that it does. If both pages are going to be modifying same array of values (for example) they need to be careful not to blank or otherwise mangle each other's items.

Comment: thanks:), i have only just started using wordpress as a platform and this is my first theme im designing.